# Node JS - Async - Response is sent while queries are being executed

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using the below piece of code to execute some set of queries and send the response of doing some validations on query results. For this scenario, I am using async module in Node JS.

```
async.series([
           function(callback){
               common.commonValidations(db);
               callback();
           },
           function(callback){
                console.log('second function');
                res.end(JSON.stringify(gErrors));
                callback();
           }

        ], function(err){
            console.log('sending res to client');
            console.log(err);
        });
```

`common.commonValidations(db)` function is used to execute few db2 queries.

Here my issue is, though I am using async module, the response is sent to the client while the query execution is going on. As per my understanding of async module, the second function in the array is executed once the first function is done with it's job.

Can someone help me on this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Let me guess, `common.commonValidations(db)` is also an async function? The thing is, it's `async` meaning the first function is executed and completed immediately, it doesn't wait for `common.commonValidations` to get a response, which is why the response is sent (i.e. the second function) is executed virtually immediately.

Comment: @Quentin my question is, how can I fix my code to send response back only after all queries are executed and validations are done?

Comment: @NaveenChappa — Don't call your callbacks until your queries are complete.

Comment: @Adam, when the call goes to second function, first function is still executing the queries. First function didn't finish it's job. Is there any solution how I can keep the first function waiting till validation on query results is done?

Comment: Can someone please help me? This issue is driving me crazy for last few days. Your help is very much appreciated. This issue is effecting my deliverables.

Comment: @NaveenChappa - as far as I can see, there is absolutely no need for node-async here. `common.commonValidations` is already asynchronous. You have two options - modify `common.commonValidations` to return a promise or allow it to accept success/error callbacks. Both of these options differ in their implementation, but, in effect, do the exact same thing: allow you to execute code once `common.commonValidations` has completed it's asynchronous work. To tell you explicitly how to do this, we'd need to see the code for that method.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `common.commonValidations(db)`  is an asynchronous function, but you are not waiting for it to be done. you are calling `callback()` function before the answer for `commonValidations` comes back.

one possible change might be like

```
common.commonValidations(db,function(err,data) {
  //check error
  //process data
  //and then
  callback()
})
```

Comment: I tried above solution. call did not got to second function after execution of first function is done. I put a console log also, nothing is printed. I am testing it through postman tool, it shows that request is still processing.

Comment: async.series([
     function(callback){
      common.commonValidations(db, function(err, data){
       console.log('validations are done');
       callback();
      });
      
     },
     function(callback){
    console.log('second function');
    res.end(JSON.stringify(gErrors));
    callback();
     }
                
  ], function(err){
   console.log('callback function');
   console.log(err);
  });